# Where is config kernel file in ubuntu10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am trying to follow these instructions http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc

and it is telling me to edit my kernel config. I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 3):

In order to modify your kernel configuration, you will need to rebuild the kernel entirely.  It is a great learning experience, but note that a broken kernel can result in an unbootable system.  Here is how you go about configuring and compiling your own [kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

You may want to just check that the kernel options you need are not already available:

```
zgrep CONFIG_ATH_COMMON /proc/config.gz
zgrep ATH9K /proc/config.gz
```

If these are set as required, then no need to build a kernel.